# typescript ngrx type mismatch between (string|number)[] and string[]|number[]

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I am trying to upgrade my angular app to 5.2.10 with other following libraries:
ngrx 5.2.0
typescript: 2.6.2
tslint 5.10.0

and hitting following errors during angular compilation:

`

```
ERROR in src/app/**/xxx-state.ts(301,5): error TS2322: Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] | number[]'.
  Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
    Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
src/app/***/xxx-state.ts(305,5): error TS2322: Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[] | number[]'.
  Type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
```

`

`

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((searchElement: string, fromIndex?: number) => number) | ((searchElement: number, fromIndex?: nu...' has no compatible call signatures.
```

`

I am using @ngrx/entity library to derive our data state interfaces from following EntityState interface defined in 'module.d.ts' file of ngrx.

`

```
export interface EntityState<T> {
    ids: string[] | number[];
    entities: Dictionary<T>;
}
```

`

any pointers to resolve these errors?

Comment: You've shown the declaration for the `string[] | number[]`, but what's the code that effects the `(string | number)[]`? You should use one or the other, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(string|number)[]` is an array that can contain string or number elements

`string[] | number[]` is EITHER an array of strings OR an array of numbers.

First would allow arrays like `[1, "2", 3]`, second would not allow them. Thus the compiler complains, for your safety. Solution: use only one of the two.